# Django Rest Framework (DRF) Refuses to Validate Data with Foreign Keys in Update (PUT) Request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Using Django REST Framework (DRF), I am trying to follow the DRF documentation for nested serializers provided by [this link](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships).  For the moment, let's assume that my code looks like the following:

***models.py***

```
class PvlEntry(models.Model):

    pvl_project = models.OneToOneField("review.ProjectList", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='pvl_project')
    pvl_reviewer = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+')
    pvl_worktype_is_correct = models.BooleanField(blank=False, null=False)
    pvl_hw_description = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)

class ProjectList(models.Model):
    """ 
    """
    project_number = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    project_manager = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=255, null=False)
    project_name = models.CharField(blank=False,
                                          max_length=255,
                                          null=False)
    project_description = models.CharField(blank=True,
                                         max_length=1024,
                                         null=True)
```

***views.py***

```
class PvlEntryListCreateAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    """ This view is leveraged for jsGrid so that we can have jsGrid produce
        a JavaScript enabled view for actions like editing and filtering of
        the project vetting list.
    """
    queryset = PvlEntry.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PvlEntrySerializer
    name = 'listcreate-pvlentry'

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = self.queryset.all()

        return qs

class PvlEntryRetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    """ Leveraged for jsGrid
    """
    queryset = PvlEntry.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PvlEntrySerializer
    name = 'rud-pvlentry'
```

***serializers.py***

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'id',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email'
        ]

class ProjectListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ProjectList
        fields = '__all__'

class PvlEntrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    pvl_project = ProjectListSerializer()
    pvl_reviewer = UserSerializer()
   
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        print(validated_data)
        return super(PvlEntrySerializer, self).update(self, instance, validated_data)

    class Meta:
        model = PvlEntry
        fields = '__all__'
```

Now, I understand that as this code sits now, it's not a writeable serializer.  However, with the above code in place, should I not at least get past the serializer's validation of the data?

Using the DRF browsable API, when I attempt a PUT operation which is using the RetriveUpdateDestroy built-in API view, I get an error similar to the following:

```
PUT /pvl/grid/11    
HTTP 400 Bad Request
Allow: GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "pvl_project": {
        "project_number": [
            "pvl entry with this project number already exists."
        ]
    }
}
```

Again, I understand that I can't perform an update (PUT) with the code as it is now, but shouldn't it at least pass the serialization/validation phase?  I'm not performing the creation of a new record, either.  I'm only attempting to perform an update.  So, why should validation be concerned with whether or not a "pvl entry with this project number" already exists?

There are a lot of posts on stackoverflow that touch on or dance around this issue but I've not been able to lean on any of them for a resolution for some reason.

I have also tried going back and replacing the nested serializers with `PrimaryKeyRelatedFields` but that approach doesn't return the related data, only references to the related data.

I have also experimented with separate serializers but that approach doesn't work well for the jsGrid JavaScript that I've implemented to consume the data in my template.

Surely there's a simple resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** solution is that you can use `PATCH` method instead of `PUT` and don't send `pvl_project` in form/ajax data (remember to set required attibute like `pvl_project = ProjectListSerializer(required=False)`.

Problem is that in drf `PUT` request method tries to replace all provided data in the given instance at one - which means it will firstly analyze that there is no `PvlEntry.pvl_project` property duplicates **because** its `OneToOneField`.

`PATCH` on the other hand can update data `partialy` (u can analyze [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53767035/10619554) problem) and you don't even care about `required=False` serializer attribute because it will only update data provided in request (how to update partial by `PUT` method is answered in my last annotation).

**Second**

Now when we have first concept resolved we can move on and make this serializer to work. Lets' assume that you have [uuid](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield) attribute set on **every** model (using `id` field is not the best practice) and you want to set `pvl_project` by the given `uuid` attribute value.

You can override `to_internal_value` method in `ProjectListSerializer` which is used on saving instance and simply search for the given object by the given data.

```
class ProjectListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProjectList
        fields = '__all__'
    
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        # you can validate data here for sure that provided data is correct uuid string
        try:
            return ProjectList.objects.get(uuid=data)
        except ProjectList.DoesNotExist:
            raise ValidationError(['Project list with the given uuid does not exist'])
```

This serializer works now like a good elastic switch between json <-> api <-> django model instance world.

Comment: What you've provided makes abundant sense to me.  Thank you!  I'm going to leave this open temporarily until I can get to play around with it tomorrow and then I'll provide credit to you for the answer.  Thanks again!

Comment: thanks again for your assistance here.  Appreciated!